# Get child value if another child value matches

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have an XML file I need to parse from the shell. It looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<things>
    <thing>
        <foo>123</foo>
        <bar>false</bar>
    </thing>
    <thing>
        <bar>true</bar>
        <foo>abc</foo>
    </thing>
</things>
```

Note that the order of the child nodes of `thing`s is arbitrary. In my real-world data, there are a couple of other child nodes inside each `thing`.

Now, the value of `foo` is unique. I need to get the value of the child node `bar` for the `thing` whose child `foo`'s value is, say, `abc`. I've tried to use an XPath query with `xmllint` but no luck. I can't get a match; or, if I just test with a more general query, I get the entire tree.

```
$ xmllint --pattern //thing[foo='abc']/bar test.xml
xmllint: No match.
$ xmllint --pattern //thing/bar test.xml
(the whole tree)
```

I was hoping just to get `true`.

What am I doing wrong? I don't have access to the `--xpath` flag other questions mention, so if that's the answer then I'm out of luck.

Comment: The way I tend to deal with problems like this is to start reducing the expression: try `//thing[foo='abc']` first, if it didn't work, try `//thing[foo]` and so on. On the face of it, the XPath expression looks correct but there could be a number of reasons why it doesn't match, namespace being one of them.

Comment: @biziclop No match on either. Even something as simple as `//foo` gives me the whole tree. Can you explain what you mean by namespace?

Comment: When you say your XML looks "somewhat like this", what does it actually look like?

Comment: @JLRishe There are up to 4 children per `thing`, and of course they're not called `thing`s, `foo`, or `bar`, but these should all be irrelevant.

Comment: Can you show us the actual opening tag that corresponds to "things"? Have you removed any attribute-like text in your attempt to simplify, assuming that it was irrelevant?

Comment: @JLRishe None of the tags have attributes. I've literally only renamed things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this command:

```
xmllint --xpath '//thing[foo="abc"]/bar/text()' test.xml
```

Another command:

```
echo 'cat //thing[foo="abc"]/bar/text()' | xmllint --shell test.xml
```

Also try `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//thing[foo="abc"]/bar' -v 'text()' test.xml
```

Comment: I do not have access to the `--xpath` option. I tried it with `--pattern` as I was doing above and I got the entire tree.

Comment: Re your edit: the second option gave me `/ >  -------
false
/ > ` which I can parse after the fact. I don't have access to `xmlstarlet`. Unless you've got anything better for me, this'll do.